# QGIS 3.22 Add new memory layer vertexTool bug? pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgsvectorlayer, memory-layer

I´m creating a QGIS Plugin and I have to load a memory layer with a specific geometry. Here is the simplified code:

```
def run(self):
    if self.first_start:
        self.first_start = False
        root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        self.myGroup1 = root.addGroup("My Group 1")
    else:
        self.templayer.rollBack(True)
        QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers([self.templayer.id()])
        self.templayer = None

    self.templayer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:25832&field=gid:int", "test", "memory")
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Templayer")

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.templayer, False)
    self.myGroup1.addLayer(self.templayer)

    daten = "LineString ("
    for i in range(0, 3):
        x = random.randrange(-200, 200)
        y = random.randrange(-200, 200)
        daten += "{0} {1},".format(x, y)
        i += 1
    daten = daten[:-1] + ")"
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(daten))
    self.templayer.startEditing()
    gid = 1
    geom = QgsGeometry().fromWkt(daten)
    feature = QgsFeature(self.templayer.fields())
    feature.setGeometry(geom)
    feature.setAttribute(0, gid)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("feature: {0}".format(feature.isValid()))
    self.templayer.addFeature(feature=feature)
    self.templayer.commitChanges(False)
    self.iface.setActiveLayer(self.templayer)
    self.iface.actionVertexToolActiveLayer().trigger()
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("layer: {0}".format(str(self.templayer.isValid())))
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("---------------")
```

Sometimes the vertexTool does not work (layer and feature are valid).

[image]

It hightlights one of the previous geometry instead of the current. Is it a bug in QGIS or is the workflow of loading the layer and adding the feature incorrect?